# Reading string values from a Cgo DLL struct

Tags: reverse-engineering, frida

I am trying to reverse engineer a 64-bit DLL that was written in Go and compiled to a C DLL. I want to log the first parameter of exported `DoRequest` method.

The DLL is invoked with P/Invoke in a C# application. Using dnSpy, I can see the struct of the data is;

```
private struct Struct0
{
    // Token: 0x04000474 RID: 1140
    public string string_0;

    // Token: 0x04000475 RID: 1141
    public string string_1;

    // Token: 0x04000476 RID: 1142
    public string string_2;

    // Token: 0x04000477 RID: 1143
    public string string_3;

    // Token: 0x04000478 RID: 1144
    public string }{__>_;

    // Token: 0x04000479 RID: 1145
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)]
    public string string_4;

    // Token: 0x0400047A RID: 1146
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)]
    public string string_5;

    // Token: 0x0400047B RID: 1147
    public string string_6;

    // Token: 0x0400047C RID: 1148
    public string string_7;

    // Token: 0x0400047D RID: 1149
    public string string_8;

    // Token: 0x0400047E RID: 1150
    public string string_9;

    // Token: 0x0400047F RID: 1151
    public int int_0;

    // Token: 0x04000480 RID: 1152
    public int int_1;

    // Token: 0x04000481 RID: 1153
    public string string_10;

    // Token: 0x04000482 RID: 1154
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool bool_0;

    // Token: 0x04000483 RID: 1155
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool bool_1;

    // Token: 0x04000484 RID: 1156
    public string string_11;

    // Token: 0x04000485 RID: 1157
    public int int_2;

    // Token: 0x04000486 RID: 1158
    public uint uint_0;
}
```

This is a screenshot of the method from IDA:

[image]

I have started writing a Frida hook;

```
var doRequest = Module.getExportByName("client64.dll", "DoRequest");

Interceptor.attach(doRequest, {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        console.log("Hooked DoRequest");
        var structPointer = (args[0]);
        console.log("structPointer : " + structPointer);            
    }
});
```

However I'm not sure where to go next. How can I read each property of the struct?

Comment: Usually structs are just a base pointer and then in memory all the entries one after another. So you may get the values by incrementing the base struct pointer (which should be the argument) by the default pointer size. So `ptr(args[0])` should be the pointer to the first element, `ptr(args[0]).add(8)` to the second, ...

Comment: Hi @Robert , this didn't work for me unfortunately. The string representation of `ptr(args[0])` was a few jumbled characters: `��oe_☻`

Comment: The method looks like a C++ method of a class. In such methods the first argument is `this` so it is a pointer to the class instance. The first method Parameter is thus present in  `args[1]`...

Comment: I managed to solve this myself; `Memory.readCString(a1[0].readPointer())`. I could then get each struct member by adding 8 bytes; `Memory.readCString(a1[0].add(8).readPointer())`

Comment: Please write a full answer with your code and description so other users can learn from it.